# Asterisk receiving code 503 with SIPML5 and MYSQL

Tags: asterisk, webrtc

I did make work a audio call between two browsers using asterisk 11.16    and SipML5, when my users are in sip.conf file.

Than I tried one user in sip.conf and another in MYSQL, and it works! So in the final step, both clients in MYSQL no luck.

The media request only happens in one side, and after some time the caller receives a 503 code.
Any clues?

Asterisk:

```
 == WebSocket connection from 'IP:PORT' for protocol 'sip' accepted using version '13'
 == WebSocket connection from 'IP:PORT' for protocol 'sip' accepted using version '13'
-- Registered SIP '000001' at IP:PORT
   > Saved useragent "IM-client/OMA1.0 sipML5-v1.0.0.0" for peer 000001
-- Registered SIP '002670' at IP:PORT
   > Saved useragent "IM-client/OMA1.0 sipML5-v1.0.0.0" for peer 002670
== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
-- Executing [000001@from-internal:1] Dial("SIP/002670-00000002", "SIP/000001,60") in new stack

== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
-- Called SIP/000001

servidor-asterisk*CLI> core show channels
Channel              Location             State   Application(Data)
SIP/002670-00000002  000001@from-internal Ring    Dial(SIP/000001,60)
SIP/000001-00000003  000001@from-internal Down    AppDial((Outgoing Line))
 2 active channels
1 active call
2 calls processed

    -- SIP/000001-00000003 is circuit-busy
  == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/1/0)
-- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/002670-00000002' status is 'CONGESTION'

 [Mar 20 16:08:48] WARNING[22762]: chan_sip.c:4020 retrans_pkt: Retransmission timeout reached on transmission 1c4882477bd3a6cd3541e672267d9356@IP:PORT for seqno 102 (Critical Request) -- See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions

Packet timed out after 32000ms with no response
```

Caller:

```
"SIPML5 API version = 1.5.222" sip_api.js:1:16348
"Sistema -> Streaming nativo da webcam suportado. Iniciando camera..." IP:3001:556:3 Sistema -> Captura iniciada!" IP:3001:590:2
{id_interno: "2670", id_usuario_d: 1, nome: "Kim", sexo: "F", foto: "apres20150317174729.jpg", cidade: "Santa Cruz do Sul", favorito: false,    red_nome: "Bapo", red_icone: "i_logo_bapo.png"} IP:3001:415
"User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101    Firefox/36.0" sip_api.js:1:16348
"WebSocket supported = yes" sip_api.js:1:16348
"Navigator friendly name = firefox" sip_api.js:1:16348
"OS friendly name = windows" sip_api.js:1:16348
"Have WebRTC = yes" sip_api.js:1:16348
"Have GUM = yes" sip_api.js:1:16348
"Engine initialized" sip_api.js:1:16348
"s_websocket_server_url=ws://IP:8088/ws" sip_api.js:1:16348
"s_sip_outboundproxy_url=(null)" sip_api.js:1:16348
"b_rtcweb_breaker_enabled=no" sip_api.js:1:16348
"b_click2call_enabled=no" sip_api.js:1:16348
"b_early_ims=no" sip_api.js:1:16348
"b_enable_media_stream_cache=yes" sip_api.js:1:16348
"o_bandwidth={}" sip_api.js:1:16348
"o_video_size={}" sip_api.js:1:16348
"SIP stack start: proxy='ns313841.ovh.net:12060', realm='<sip:IP>',     impi='002670', impu='"002670"<sip:002670@IP:8088>'" sip_api.js:1:16348
"Connecting to 'ws://IP:8088/ws'" sip_api.js:1:16348
"|> SipStack iniciado!" IP:3001:765:3
"__tsip_transport_ws_onopen" sip_api.js:1:16348
"State machine: tsip_dialog_register_Started_2_InProgress_X_oRegister" sip_api.js:1:16348
"SEND: REGISTER sip:IP SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/WS         df7jal23ls0d.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK8HE4oAeuBcyOUbrE76PyBt4BptE9BsZ9;rport

From: "002670"<sip:002670@IP:8088>;tag=yd16vtKL2Ct5W8bgw8ea

To: "002670"<sip:002670@IP:8088>

Contact: "002670"<sip:002670@df7jal23ls0d.invalid;rtcweb-breaker=no;transport=ws>;expires=1800;click2call=no

Call-ID: fd274211-0331-7a38-7320-3fdb750d62c8

CSeq: 52764 REGISTER

Content-Length: 0

Max-Forwards: 70

Authorization: Digest        username="002670",realm="IP",nonce="",uri="sip:IP",response=""

User-Agent: IM-client/OMA1.0 sipML5-v1.0.0.0

Organization: Tra La Lala Corp.

Supported: path



" sip_api.js:1:16348
"__tsip_transport_ws_onmessage" sip_api.js:1:16348
"recv=SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized

Via: SIP/2.0/WS df7jal23ls0d.invalid;rport;received=IP;branch=z9hG4bK8HE4oAeuBcyOUbrE76PyBt4BptE9BsZ9

From: "002670"<sip:002670@IP:8088>;tag=yd16vtKL2Ct5W8bgw8ea

To: "002670"<sip:002670@IP:8088>;tag=as67f4562a

Call-ID: fd274211-0331-7a38-7320-3fdb750d62c8

CSeq: 52764 REGISTER

Content-Length: 0

Server: Asterisk PBX 11.16.0

Allow:     INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH,MESSAGE

Supported: replaces,timer

WWW-Authenticate: Digest     realm="IP",nonce="4d3f211c",stale=FALSE,algorithm=MD5



" sip_api.js:1:16348
"State machine:     tsip_dialog_register_InProgress_2_InProgress_X_401_407_421_494"     sip_api.js:1:16348
"SEND: REGISTER sip:IP SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/WS df7jal23ls0d.invalid;branch=z9hG4bKtWK7SzDKHDcC7wMsgRxtM8tevHiZsSET;rport

From: "002670"<sip:002670@IP:8088>;tag=yd16vtKL2Ct5W8bgw8ea

To: "002670"<sip:002670@IP:8088>

Contact: "002670"<sip:002670@df7jal23ls0d.invalid;rtcweb-breaker=no;transport=ws>;expires=1800;click2call=no

Call-ID: fd274211-0331-7a38-7320-3fdb750d62c8

CSeq: 52765 REGISTER

Content-Length: 0

Max-Forwards: 70

Authorization: Digest     username="002670",realm="IP",nonce="4d3f211c",uri="sip:IP",response="27379c933ca33f75ce31240d6385c254",algorithm=MD5

User-Agent: IM-client/OMA1.0 sipML5-v1.0.0.0

Organization: Tra La Lala Corp.

Supported: path



   " sip_api.js:1:16348
"State machine: c0000_Started_2_Outgoing_X_oINVITE" sip_api.js:1:16348
"PeerConnectionClass = function mozRTCPeerConnection() {
    [native code]
} SessionDescriptionClass = function mozRTCSessionDescription() {
    [native code]
} IceCandidateClass = function mozRTCIceCandidate() {
    [native code]
}" sip_api.js:1:16348
"ICE servers:[{"url":"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}]" sip_api.js:1:16348
"__tsip_transport_ws_onmessage" sip_api.js:1:16348
"recv=SIP/2.0 200 OK

Via: SIP/2.0/WS df7jal23ls0d.invalid;rport;received=IP;    branch=z9hG4bKtWK7SzDKHDcC7wMsgRxtM8tevHiZsSET

From: "002670"<sip:002670@IP:8088>;tag=yd16vtKL2Ct5W8bgw8ea

To: "002670"<sip:002670@IP:8088>;tag=as67f4562a

Contact: <sip:002670@df7jal23ls0d.invalid;rtcweb-breaker=no;transport=ws>;expires=1800

Call-ID: fd274211-0331-7a38-7320-3fdb750d62c8

CSeq: 52765 REGISTER

Expires: 1800

Content-Length: 0

Server: Asterisk PBX 11.16.0

Allow:     INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH,MESSAGE

Supported: replaces,timer

Date: 20 Mar 2015 19:08:11 GMT;20



" sip_api.js:1:16348
"State machine: tsip_dialog_register_InProgress_2_Connected_X_2xx" sip_api.js:1:16348
"|> ELSE -> sipEventsListener: Media Requested" IP:3001:882:3
{type: "m_permission_requested", description: "Media Requested", o_event: Object} IP:3001:883
Mandatory/optional in createOffer options is deprecated! Use     {"offerToReceiveAudio":true,"offerToReceiveVideo":false,"mozDontOfferDataChan    nel":true} instead (note the case difference)! <desconhecido>
"onGetUserMediaSuccess" sip_api.js:1:16348
"createOffer" sip_api.js:1:16348
"|> ELSE -> sipEventsListener: Media Accepted" IP:3001:882:3
{type: "m_permission_accepted", description: "Media Accepted", o_event: Object} IP:3001:883
"|> ELSE -> sipEventsListener: Media Added" IP:3001:882:3
{type: "m_stream_audio_local_added", description: "Media Added", o_event: Object, session: Object} IP:3001:883
"onCreateSdpSuccess" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onSignalingstateChange:have-local-offer" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onSetLocalDescriptionSuccess" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted" sip_api.js:1:16348
"SEND: INVITE sip:000001@IP SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/WS     df7jal23ls0d.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK0LJ9ofmfgrwoPW9WopzEIFHZIVTx6TgE;rport

From: "002670"<sip:002670@IP:8088>;tag=Sw9d0BOqG8wZCH8czu7B

To: <sip:000001@IP>

Contact: "002670"<sip:002670@df7jal23ls0d.invalid;rtcweb-breaker=no;    click2call=no;transport=ws>;+g.oma.sip-im;language="en,fr"

Call-ID: 4448657e-6b45-f1ae-2d45-417b49a19bd9

CSeq: 18237 INVITE

Content-Type: application/sdp

Content-Length: 1216

Max-Forwards: 70

User-Agent: IM-client/OMA1.0 sipML5-v1.0.0.0

Organization: Tra La Lala Corp.



v=0

o=Mozilla-SIPUA-36.0.1 5071 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0

s=Doubango Telecom - firefox

t=0 0

a=ice-ufrag:2969df08

a=ice-pwd:15fdd4182c02748e9d1a6ef9c2cbe979

a=fingerprint:sha-256     BB:C9:2E:56:BE:65:3D:4F:24:2A:AA:97:17:6F:C8:BB:8D:99:BA:5E:3E:F3:AD:D9:82:63:B7:8E:61:75:D0:BA

m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101

c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0

a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2

a=ptime:20

a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:101 0-15

a=sendrecv

a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level

a=setup:actpass

a=rtcp-mux

a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2128609535 192.168.1.113 56842 typ host

a=candidate:2 1 UDP 2128543999 192.168.1.104 56843 typ host

a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2128609534 192.168.1.113 56844 typ host

a=candidate:2 2 UDP 2128543998 192.168.1.104 56845 typ host

a=candidate:1 1 UDP 1692467199 IP 56842 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.113 rport 56842

a=candidate:3 1 UDP 1692401663 IP 56843 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.104 rport 56843

a=candidate:1 2 UDP 1692467198 IP 56844 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.113 rport 56844

a=candidate:3 2 UDP 1692401662 IP 56845 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.104 rport 56845

    " sip_api.js:1:16348
    "onIceCandidate = complete" sip_api.js:1:16348
"ICE GATHERING COMPLETED!" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted but no local sdp request is pending"     sip_api.js:1:16444
"onIceCandidate = complete" sip_api.js:1:16348
"ICE GATHERING COMPLETED!" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted but no local sdp request is pending" sip_api.js:1:16444
"onIceCandidate = complete" sip_api.js:1:16348
    "ICE GATHERING COMPLETED!" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted but no local sdp request is pending" sip_api.js:1:16444
"onIceCandidate = complete" sip_api.js:1:16348
"ICE GATHERING COMPLETED!" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted but no local sdp request is pending" sip_api.js:1:16444
"onIceCandidate = complete" sip_api.js:1:16348
"ICE GATHERING COMPLETED!" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted but no local sdp request is pending" sip_api.js:1:16444
"onIceCandidate = complete" sip_api.js:1:16348
"ICE GATHERING COMPLETED!" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted but no local sdp request is pending" sip_api.js:1:16444
"onIceCandidate = complete" sip_api.js:1:16348
"ICE GATHERING COMPLETED!" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted but no local sdp request is pending"         sip_api.js:1:16444
"onIceCandidate = complete" sip_api.js:1:16348
"ICE GATHERING COMPLETED!" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted but no local sdp request is pending" sip_api.js:1:16444
"onIceCandidate = complete" sip_api.js:1:16348
"ICE GATHERING COMPLETED!" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onIceGatheringCompleted but no local sdp request is pending" sip_api.js:1:16444
"__tsip_transport_ws_onmessage" sip_api.js:1:16348
"recv=SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized

Via: SIP/2.0/WS df7jal23ls0d.invalid;rport;received=IP;    branch=z9hG4bK0LJ9ofmfgrwoPW9WopzEIFHZIVTx6TgE

From: "002670"<sip:002670@IP:8088>;tag=Sw9d0BOqG8wZCH8czu7B

To: <sip:000001@IP>;tag=as3720237e

Call-ID: 4448657e-6b45-f1ae-2d45-417b49a19bd9

CSeq: 18237 INVITE

Content-Length: 0

Server: Asterisk PBX 11.16.0

    Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH,MESSAGE

Supported: replaces,timer

WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="IP",nonce="18c6a5f8",stale=FALSE,algorithm=MD5



" sip_api.js:1:16348
"SEND: ACK sip:000001@IP SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/WS df7jal23ls0d.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK0LJ9ofmfgrwoPW9WopzEIFHZIVTx6TgE;rport

From: "002670"<sip:002670@IP:8088>;tag=Sw9d0BOqG8wZCH8czu7B

To: <sip:000001@IP>;tag=as3720237e

Call-ID: 4448657e-6b45-f1ae-2d45-417b49a19bd9

CSeq: 18237 ACK

Content-Length: 0

Max-Forwards: 70



" sip_api.js:1:16348
"State machine: x0000_Any_2_Any_X_i401_407_INVITE" sip_api.js:1:16348
"SEND: INVITE sip:000001@IP SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/WS     df7jal23ls0d.invalid;branch=z9hG4bKBTtIE3wTk1dg8dAxX1IQl5p63SNt4rlV;rport

From: "002670"<sip:002670@IP:8088>;tag=Sw9d0BOqG8wZCH8czu7B

To: <sip:000001@IP>

Contact: "002670"<sip:002670@df7jal23ls0d.invalid;rtcweb-breaker=no;        click2call=no;transport=ws>;+g.oma.sip-im;language="en,fr"

Call-ID: 4448657e-6b45-f1ae-2d45-417b49a19bd9

CSeq: 18238 INVITE

Content-Type: application/sdp

Content-Length: 1216

Max-Forwards: 70

Authorization: Digest     username="002670",realm="IP",nonce="18c6a5f8",uri="sip:000001@IP",response="07d31757427a917482a68ae9de6d739d",algorithm=MD5

User-Agent: IM-client/OMA1.0 sipML5-v1.0.0.0

Organization: Tra La Lala Corp.



v=0

o=Mozilla-SIPUA-36.0.1 5071 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0

s=Doubango Telecom - firefox

t=0 0

a=ice-ufrag:2969df08

a=ice-pwd:15fdd4182c02748e9d1a6ef9c2cbe979

a=fingerprint:sha-256     BB:C9:2E:56:BE:65:3D:4F:24:2A:AA:97:17:6F:C8:BB:8D:99:BA:5E:3E:F3:AD:D9:82:63    :B7:8E:61:75:D0:BA

m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101

c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0

a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2

a=ptime:20

a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:101 0-15

a=sendrecv

a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level

a=setup:actpass

a=rtcp-mux

a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2128609535 192.168.1.113 56842 typ host

a=candidate:2 1 UDP 2128543999 192.168.1.104 56843 typ host

a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2128609534 192.168.1.113 56844 typ host

a=candidate:2 2 UDP 2128543998 192.168.1.104 56845 typ host

=candidate:1 1 UDP 1692467199 IP 56842 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.113     rport 56842

a=candidate:3 1 UDP 1692401663 IP 56843 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.104 rport 56843

a=candidate:1 2 UDP 1692467198 IP 56844 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.113 rport 56844

a=candidate:3 2 UDP 1692401662 IP 56845 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.104 rport 56845

    " sip_api.js:1:16348
    "__tsip_transport_ws_onmessage" sip_api.js:1:16348
"recv=SIP/2.0 100 Trying

Via: SIP/2.0/WS df7jal23ls0d.invalid;rport;received=IP;branch=z9hG4bKBTtIE3wTk1dg8dAxX1IQl5p63SNt4rlV

From: "002670"<sip:002670@IP:8088>;tag=Sw9d0BOqG8wZCH8czu7B

To: <sip:000001@IP>

Contact: <sip:000001@IP:5060;transport=WS>

Call-ID: 4448657e-6b45-f1ae-2d45-417b49a19bd9

CSeq: 18238 INVITE

Content-Length: 0

Server: Asterisk PBX 11.16.0

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH,MESSAGE

Supported: replaces,timer



" sip_api.js:1:16348
"State machine: x0000_Any_2_Any_X_i1xx" sip_api.js:1:16348
"__tsip_transport_ws_onmessage" sip_api.js:1:16348
"recv=SIP/2.0 503 Service Unavailable

Via: SIP/2.0/WS df7jal23ls0d.invalid;rport;received=IP;branch=z9hG4bKBTtIE3wTk1dg8dAxX1IQl5p63SNt4rlV

From: "002670"<sip:002670@IP:8088>;tag=Sw9d0BOqG8wZCH8czu7B

To: <sip:000001@IP>;tag=as4f8494c0

Call-ID: 4448657e-6b45-f1ae-2d45-417b49a19bd9

CSeq: 18238 INVITE

Content-Length: 0

Server: Asterisk PBX 11.16.0

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH,MESSAGE

Supported: replaces,timer



" sip_api.js:1:16348
"SEND: ACK sip:000001@IP SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/WS df7jal23ls0d.invalid;branch=z9hG4bKBTtIE3wTk1dg8dAxX1IQl5p63SNt4rlV;rport

From: "002670"<sip:002670@IP:8088>;tag=Sw9d0BOqG8wZCH8czu7B

To: <sip:000001@IP>;tag=as4f8494c0

Call-ID: 4448657e-6b45-f1ae-2d45-417b49a19bd9

CSeq: 18238 ACK

Content-Length: 0

Max-Forwards: 70



" sip_api.js:1:16348
"State machine: c0000_Outgoing_2_Terminated_X_i300_to_i699INVITE" sip_api.js:1:16348
"=== INVITE Dialog terminated ===" sip_api.js:1:16348
"onSignalingstateChange:closed" sip_api.js:1:16348
"PeerConnection::stop()" sip_api.js:1:16348
"The FSM is in the final state" sip_api.js:1:16444
```

Called:

```
"SIPML5 API version = 1.5.222" sip_api.js:1:16348
"Sistema -> Streaming nativo da webcam suportado. Iniciando camera..." IP:3001:556:3
"Sistema -> Captura iniciada!" IP:3001:590:2
"User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0" sip_api.js:1:16348
"WebSocket supported = yes" sip_api.js:1:16348
"Navigator friendly name = firefox" sip_api.js:1:16348
"OS friendly name = windows" sip_api.js:1:16348
"Have WebRTC = yes" sip_api.js:1:16348
"Have GUM = yes" sip_api.js:1:16348
"Engine initialized" sip_api.js:1:16348
"s_websocket_server_url=ws://IP:8088/ws" sip_api.js:1:16348
"s_sip_outboundproxy_url=(null)" sip_api.js:1:16348
"b_rtcweb_breaker_enabled=no" sip_api.js:1:16348
"b_click2call_enabled=no" sip_api.js:1:16348
"b_early_ims=no" sip_api.js:1:16348
"b_enable_media_stream_cache=yes" sip_api.js:1:16348
"o_bandwidth={}" sip_api.js:1:16348
"o_video_size={}" sip_api.js:1:16348
"SIP stack start: proxy='ns313841.ovh.net:10060', realm='<sip:IP>', impi='000001', impu='"000001"<sip:000001@IP:8088>'" sip_api.js:1:16348
"Connecting to 'ws://IP:8088/ws'" sip_api.js:1:16348
"|> SipStack iniciado!" IP:3001:765:3
"__tsip_transport_ws_onopen" sip_api.js:1:16348
{id_interno: "1", id_usuario_d: 2670, nome: "Coisa", sexo: "M", foto:     "Coisa20150317152721.jpg", cidade: "Santa Cruz do Sul", favorito: true, red_nome: "Bapo", red_icone: "i_logo_bapo.png"} IP:3001:415
"State machine: tsip_dialog_register_Started_2_InProgress_X_oRegister" sip_api.js:1:16348
"SEND: REGISTER sip:IP SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/WS df7jal23ls0d.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK2zpqnfk8SZSCtFZJhDfT3xeMOrJhkTuX;rport

From: "000001"<sip:000001@IP:8088>;tag=21sD3hs1CpOqrOBO9NsX

To: "000001"<sip:000001@IP:8088>

Contact: "000001"<sip:000001@df7jal23ls0d.invalid;rtcweb-breaker=no;transport=ws>;expires=1800;click2call=no

Call-ID: 812515ca-07e6-98e7-9892-f18a83d2aa30

CSeq: 22917 REGISTER

Content-Length: 0

Max-Forwards: 70

Authorization: Digest username="000001",realm="IP",nonce="",uri="sip:IP",response=""

User-Agent: IM-client/OMA1.0 sipML5-v1.0.0.0

Organization: Tra La Lala Corp.

Supported: path



" sip_api.js:1:16348
"__tsip_transport_ws_onmessage" sip_api.js:1:16348
"recv=SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized

Via: SIP/2.0/WS df7jal23ls0d.invalid;rport;received=IP;    branch=z9hG4bK2zpqnfk8SZSCtFZJhDfT3xeMOrJhkTuX

From: "000001"<sip:000001@IP:8088>;tag=21sD3hs1CpOqrOBO9NsX

To: "000001"<sip:000001@IP:8088>;tag=as427ae015

Call-ID: 812515ca-07e6-98e7-9892-f18a83d2aa30

CSeq: 22917 REGISTER

Content-Length: 0

Server: Asterisk PBX 11.16.0

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH,MESSAGE

Supported: replaces,timer

WWW-Authenticate: Digest     realm="IP",nonce="7931c3b8",stale=FALSE,algorithm=MD5



" sip_api.js:1:16348
"State machine: tsip_dialog_register_InProgress_2_InProgress_X_401_407_421_494"     sip_api.js:1:16348
"SEND: REGISTER sip:IP SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/WS df7jal23ls0d.invalid;branch=z9hG4bKEXbpaIGIxGtPKm1WPqUtFLnqSlfCNRZB;rport

From: "000001"<sip:000001@IP:8088>;tag=21sD3hs1CpOqrOBO9NsX

To: "000001"<sip:000001@IP:8088>

Contact: "000001"<sip:000001@df7jal23ls0d.invalid;rtcweb-breaker=no;transport=ws>;expires=1800;click2call=no

Call-ID: 812515ca-07e6-98e7-9892-f18a83d2aa30

CSeq: 22918 REGISTER

Content-Length: 0

Max-Forwards: 70

Authorization: Digest username="000001",realm="IP",nonce="7931c3b8",uri="sip:IP",response="2bd91f75bef84bf128996489ba8b743f",algorithm=MD5

User-Agent: IM-client/OMA1.0 sipML5-v1.0.0.0

Organization: Tra La Lala Corp.

Supported: path



" sip_api.js:1:16348
"__tsip_transport_ws_onmessage" sip_api.js:1:16348
"recv=SIP/2.0 200 OK

Via: SIP/2.0/WS df7jal23ls0d.invalid;rport;received=IP;    branch=z9hG4bKEXbpaIGIxGtPKm1WPqUtFLnqSlfCNRZB

From: "000001"<sip:000001@IP:8088>;tag=21sD3hs1CpOqrOBO9NsX

To: "000001"<sip:000001@IP:8088>;tag=as427ae015

Contact: <sip:000001@df7jal23ls0d.invalid;rtcweb-breaker=no;transport=ws>;expires=1800

Call-ID: 812515ca-07e6-98e7-9892-f18a83d2aa30

CSeq: 22918 REGISTER

Expires: 1800

Content-Length: 0

Server: Asterisk PBX 11.16.0

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH,MESSAGE

Supported: replaces,timer

Date: 20 Mar 2015 19:08:10 GMT;20



" sip_api.js:1:16348
"State machine: tsip_dialog_register_InProgress_2_Connected_X_2xx"`
```

Comment: sounds like the issue is in your MySQL handling and the information provided from it...

Comment: But it does work with one user in mysql and another in sip.conf, if the problem was in the DB wouldnt happen for all users? the only difference in them is the name and secret.

Comment: Something may have changed in the ordering, process of the information, or any number of things. Its hard to tell without actually seeing the code and without adequate debugging information to pinpoint the issue. As it is now, your question is very very broad.

Comment: Just added some debug info from asterisk and both clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's working, for anyone else who might get this problem, the sip.conf file had a line missing:

```
[general]
udpbindaddr=0.0.0.0:5060
realm=IP ;replace with your Asterisk server public IP address or host
rtcachefriends=yes
transport=udp,ws,wss
videosupport=no
avpf=yes
icesupport=yes
directmedia=no
allowguest=no
allwaysreject=yes
rtptimeout=30
allow=all
```

the 'rtcachefriends=yes' seems to be necessary for realtime.
That and also in my mysql table the 'qualify' field was default as NULL, is suppoused to be yes.

Thats all folks!